# Grep/Sed/Awk Options

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

How could you grep or use sed or awk to parse for a dynamic length substring? Here are some examples:

I need to parse out everything except for the "XXXXX.WAV" in these strings, but the strings are not a set length.

Sometimes its like this:

```
{"filename": "/assets/JFM/imaging/19001.WAV"},
{"filename": "/assets/JFM/imaging/19307.WAV"},
{"filename": "/assets/JFM/imaging/19002.WAV"}
```

And sometimes like this:

```
 {"filename": "/assets/JFM/LN_405999/101.WAV"},
 {"filename": "/assets/JFM/LN_405999/102.WAV"},
 {"filename": "/assets/JFM/LN_405999/103.WAV"}
```

Is there a great dynamic way to parse for just the .WAV? Maybe if I start at "/" and parse until "?

Edit:

Expected output like this:

```
19001.WAV
19307.WAV
19002.WAV
```

Or:

```
101.WAV
101.WAV
103.WAV
```

Comment: What do you mean, show the expected output. Could probably just do `grep -o '/.*WAV'`

Comment: I edited to show expected output. I've tried that a a few other things but for that specifically I get the rest of the file path in output. This will give me the epxected output but obviously doesn;t work for different number of characters proceeding the .WAV: `grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^"].WAV' `

Comment: The entire purpose of these programs is to parse dynamic strings. So yes, of course it's possible.

Comment: With GNU `grep` and the `-o` option, `grep -o '[^/]*\.WAV'` should do the job.  Look for a sequence of zero or more non-slashes followed by `.WAV`.  Or `grep -E -o '[^/]+\.WAV'`.  Etc.

Comment: That is what I am looking for - I feeli dumb not being able to get to this conclusion myself. Thanks for the help @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Is your input json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `grep` as proposed in comments:

```
grep -o '[^/]\{1,\}\.WAV' yourfile
```

If the *wav* file always contains numbers, this seems more explicit (same result):

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\}\.WAV'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are `[` and `]` lines at the beginning and end of your file, it looks like your input is JSON, in which case I would recommend installing and using `jq` rather than text-based utilities, and doing something like this:

```
jq -r '.[]|.filename|split("/")[-1]'
```

But failing that, any of the tools listed will work just fine.

```
grep -o '[^/]*\.WAV'
```

or

```
sed -ne 's,.*/\([^/]*\.WAV\).*$,\1,p'
```

or

```
awk -F'"' '/WAV/ {split($4,a,"/"); print a[length(a)]}'
```

In each case there are a variety of other possible solutions as well.

Comment: The first direction I went was jq but due to the way i need to use this output for a specific web application it can't use the output of jq qithout running over it again to format it correctly. The other options format the output correct with one pass so I'm going to go with them.

Comment: Not sure I understand; the output of the `jq` command above looks just like the output of the `grep` and `sed` and `awk` commands. No extra punctuation or anything. But whatever works!

Comment: You are right - my apologies. I answered before I gave it much thought. The `jq` I implemented had this problem but your solution would fix that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
awk  -F'[{":}/]' '{print $(NF-2)}' f
19001.WAV
19307.WAV
19002.WAV
```

**OR**

```
egrep -o '[[:digit:]]{5}.WAV' f
19001.WAV
19307.WAV
19002.WAV
```

**OR**

```
egrep -o '[[:digit:]]{5}.[[:alpha:]]{3}' f
19001.WAV
19307.WAV
19002.WAV
```

You can easily change the value of digit and character as per your need for different example in egrep but awk will work fine for both case.

Answer (score 1):

Or with sed

```
$ sed 's,.*/,,; s,".*,,' x
101.WAV
102.WAV
103.WAV
```

Explanation:

- `s,.*/,,` - delete everything up to and including the rightmost `/`
- `s,".*,,` - delete everything starting with the leftmost `"` to the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

All of the programs you listed use regex to parse the names, so I will show you an example using `grep`, being probably the most basic one for this case.

There are a couple of options, depending on the exact way you define the XXX part before the ".wav".

Option 1, as you pointed out is just the file name, i.e., everything after the last slash:

```
grep -hoi "[^/]\+\.WAV"
```

This reads as "any character besides slash" (`[^/]`) repeated at least once (`\+`), followed by a literal `.WAV` (`\.WAV`).

Option 2 would be to only grab the digits before the extension:

```
grep -hoi "[[:digit:]]\+\.WAV"
```

OR

```
grep -hoi "[0-9]\+\.WAV"
```

These read as "digits" (`[[:digit:]]` and `[0-9]` mean the same thing) repeated at least once (`\+`), followed by a literal `.WAV` (`\.WAV`).

In all cases, I recommend using the flags `-h`, `-o`, `-i`, which I have concatenated into a single option `-hoi`. `-h` suppresses the file name from the output. `-o` makes `grep` only output the portion that matches. `-i` makes the match case insensitive, so should your extension ever change to `.wav` instead of `.WAV`, you'll be fine.

Also, in all cases, the input is up to you. You can pipe it in from another program, which will look like

```
program | grep -hoi "[^/]\+\.WAV"
```

You can get it from a file using stdin redirection:

```
grep -hoi "[^/]\+\.WAV" < somefile.txt
```

Or you can just pass the filename to `grep`:

```
grep -hoi "[^/]\+\.WAV" somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
awk -F'[/"]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file

19001.WAV
19307.WAV
19002.WAV
```

Comment: I considered using a `[/"]` separator, but didn't think of counting backward from the end. +1. You may want a selector there, though; if the input really is JSON, that will print the `[` and `]` lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F/ '{print substr($5,1,7)}' file

101.WAV
102.WAV
103.WAV
```